# WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state

Tags: jquery, jetty, comet, cometd

i'm working on a web application that have comet data push from server to the applications.
when i use the application, web socket disconnects with the server and due to that i miss some amount of data in the web application interface. this has caused a major issue i need to resolve.

server is jetty 7.

client is developed using jquery 1.4.2.js and jquery.cometd.js and cometd.js javascript libraries as a  java web application.

application runs through a HAProxy load balancer.

application is deployed in nginx 1.4.2

any suggestion to resolve this issue?

FYI :

I tried googling, suggestions are there to upgrade to jetty9 , do i need to update the jetty? will this only resolve the issue? do i need to update the jquery version along with comet java script libraries also?

appreciate your valuable feed back

```
comet SYMBOl|TStamp|Prev TStamp >> MUNSHAAT`R|09:39:31|93917   
SYM OLD NSNO|old|new >> MUNSHAAT`R|666|687   
onDisconnect KSE - Disconnecting comet.   
commetApi KSE - reconnect   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
onHandshake KSE- Status = true   
commetApi KSE - reconnect   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
onConnect KSE   
Price call: GET   
Price call: GET   
XHR finished loading: GET "https:///example/price?RT=25"
XHR finished loading: GET "https://example/price?RT=27"
onDisconnect KSE - Disconnecting comet.   
commetApi KSE - reconnect   
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. cometd.js? 
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. cometd.js? 
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. cometd.js? 
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. cometd.js? 
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. cometd.js? 
commetApi KSE - onsubscribe   
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. cometd.js? 
onConnect KSE   
comet sym|hed|data >> KSE|E,INS,S,TT,LTP,LTQ,CHG,PCHG,TYPE,SPL,SNO,OL|KSE|0|SAFTEC`R|064004|51.0|20000|-1.0|-1.92|S|1|693|0   
came in SYMBOl|TStamp|Prev TStamp >> SAFTEC`R|09:40:04|93931
```

--regrds, rangana

Comment: So you have requests flowing through HAProxy then Nginx then Jetty ? Are you really sure that WebSocket is supported in all those steps ? I would just expose Jetty directly to see if it works first.

Comment: i tried this step, by writing a small client application and directly connecting to the comet service. in that one also i noticed the pushed date from jetty got missed time to time. :-/

Comment: Well, there are not enough details to help you on this issue. You are welcome to join the CometD mailing lists, see http://cometd.org/. CometD does not "miss" any data to my knowledge, and it has been deployed on small and large cases, so it may just be an application mistake.

Comment: @sbordet : you are correct, there was an application mistake we found, jetty also takes data from third party connection. in that what application implementation does is when it get data , it put them to a temporary cache, the items that only hit that cache, successfully saved in that cache is served to my client application. by correcting that we were able to reduce some losses. by enabling long pooling we saw that we get the full amount of data. as i see it the problem lies in the websocket disconnections now.for the time being we have kept the long pooling enabled. :)